# Forcing a mapper to stop its execution

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a file that I divided up into splits, each split will be given to a mapper.
I want to put something like "budget time" so when the mapper exceeds this time it stops the execution of its current task and the whole tasks on which it is responsible. How can I do so in Hadoop MapReduce. In other words, how can I force the mapper to stop its execution after exceeding the budget time?

Comment: Who is responsible for keeping track of this 'budget time' ? Is it the mapper itself? If yes then I might have a solution.

Comment: Yeah the mapper itself.

Answer (score 1):

So if control of 'budget time' is in the hands of the mapper itself then you can override the `run()` of `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper` class and only execute map() till the 'budget time' elapses.

You can have it something like this:

```
public static class MapJob extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    private Text outputKey = new Text();
    private Text outputValue = new Text();
    private Date  startTime;
    private int budgetTimeInMilliSeconds;

    // in setup method set the startTime with surrent datetime
    @override
    public void setup(Context context){
        startTime = new Date();
        // also get the budgetTimeInMilliSeconds from configs
    }

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     // Do your map thing
    }

    @Override
    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        setup(context);
        while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
        Date currentTime = new Date();
            if(currentTime.getTime()-startTime.getTime() > budgetTimeInMilliSeconds) { 
                map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
            }else{
                break; // stop further execution of mapper
            }
        }
    }

    cleanup(context);
}
```

Comment: But in this case we will lose the data generated by the mapper !!! imagine if the mapper is the responsible of a data split (i.e. multi-lines in the input file), in this case, we will not even be able to keep the unhandeled data since that they were not emitted to the reduce side !!!